# Parse Server Upset Data in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to query an API to get some data then I want to upsert all of it into my table.

But for some reason I'm not having any luck.

What's the best way to go about this?

I don't think my method of doing a query in a loop is best.

```
var coin = new Parse.Object.extend("Coins");
axios.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
.then(response => {
let data = response.data;

// Put into database
data.map(entry => {
  let q = new Parse.Query(Model.Coins.className());
  q.equalTo('symbol', entry.symbol);
  q.first()
  .then(record => {
    record.set('symbol', entry.symbol);
    record.set('price_usd', entry.price_usd);
    return record.save(null, {useMasterKey: true});
  });
});
res.success(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should avoid fetching and updating objects in a loop. In order to make it better you need to use 2 things:

1. In your query, instead of using **equalTo** and **first** you need to use [containedIn](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/v1.11.0/Parse.Query.html#containedIn) for query all the records in one call. Then you need to iterate on the query results, for each record in the loop you need to do the following:

```js
record.set('symbol', entry.symbol);
record.set('price_usd', entry.price_usd);
```

2. Finally you need to use [saveAll](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/v1.11.0/Parse.Object.html#.saveAll) to save all the objects in one call (please notice that **saveAll** is static function of Parse.Object and you should pass an array into it. Please review the docs before doing it)

Answer (score 0):

Check your data. You may find you have unexpectedly updated records.

Assuming that's the entire body of a cloud function, your function initiates an asynchronous server call, then immediately tells the requestor that the operation was successful, but response isn't populated yet so you pass back undefined. However, parse-server will still run that asynchronous code.

The solution is to put the `res.success` call inside another `.then` chain, so the function won't return a response until after the server call + save finishes.

You're also going to get an uncaught error if the symbol doesn't exist on your table, though. You don't check to make sure the query returned a response to the `first()` call.